# On div click, toggle select2 dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to toggle (open/close) the drop-down menu of a select2 select box when i click on a specific div with id `"#clickme"`

Here is the code i 'm using to open the drop-down options menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#clickme").click(function(){
$("#postitemlocation").select2("open");
});

});
```

But this open only, the select2 drop-down menu. I tried

```
$("#postitemlocation").select2("toggle");
```

but doesn't work at all. Any idea ?

Comment: can you add the html that goes with this

Comment: The reason this isn't built in to the Select2 library by default is because it's not as straightforward as you might think. In order to toggle you need to know the current state of the element, ie. if it's open or closed. However as the select *always* closes when it loses focus, when you click the button to close the select it will automatically close itself. Then the button checks to determine the state of the select and sees it is closed and so opens it again. As such you can't effectively toggle the element.

Comment: you need an if to close the select2 - there is no toggle method: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your comment. Finally i used a trick to make it work using 2 different divs (triggers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments of other people i found a very simple solution that will do the trick. Sometimes simple approaches are the best.

Here is my code in case that anyone else need a similar function with select2 plugin.

```js
$("#postitemlocation").select2()

$("#clickme1").click(function() {
  $("#postitemlocation").select2("open");
  $("#clickme1").hide();
  $("#clickme2").show();
});

$("#clickme2").click(function() {
  $("#postitemlocation").select2("close");
  $("#clickme1").show();
  $("#clickme2").hide();
});
```

```css
#clickme1,
#clickme2 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#clickme2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="postitemlocation">
  <option value="">Choose a location</option>
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">London</option>
  <option value="3">Tokyo</option>
  <option value="4">Miami</option>
  <option value="5">Rome</option>
</select>
<div id="clickme1">click me</div>
<div id="clickme2">click me</div>
```